# sql bulk insert non-standard characters

Tags: sql, character-encoding, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert

I am importing data into a sql table from a csv using an xml format file.

When I perform the import it all works well but some extended characters are showing up incorrectly with things like this '▓' the one in particular is the '²'.

I am assuming it is something to do with the encoding of the file and me not telling the import how to handle it but I'm not 100% sure.

My CSV looks like the following

> "2","4567","2","234562","","MAX","","2452","m²",""," ","254352"

and my import file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"' />
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' />
  <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='"\r\n' />
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="PARCELID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="PROPID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="LOT" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="RPLAN" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="SECTION" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="PARISH" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="COUNTY" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="AREA" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="AREATYPE" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="ZONING" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="MAPID" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="LOTPLAN" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I'm importing it using the sql command

```
 BULK INSERT [parcel]
        FROM 'c:\test\PARCEL.csv'
        WITH (FORMATFILE = 'c:\test\PARCEL.xml', KEEPIDENTITY, FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPNULLS)
```

and my table structure looks like

```
[PARCELID] [int] NOT NULL
[PROPID] [int] NULL
[LOT] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[RPLAN] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[SECTION] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[PARISH] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[COUNTY] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[AREA] [nvarchar](50) NULL
[AREATYPE] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[ZONING] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[MAPID] [nvarchar](255) NULL
[LOTPLAN] [nvarchar](255) NULL
```

I have tried setting the bulk insert datafiletype to both 'widenative' and 'widechar' but to no avail.

Is there something else I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I needed to set the collation on the column itself like

```
<FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR='","' COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS" />
```